# WYSIWYG free editor with cross browser client side spell check?

Tags: asp.net, wysiwyg

I want to use a free WYSIWYG edior in my asp.net site. Actually I tried some (ajaxtoolkit html editor, Tiny Mce, FCK, NiceEditor) but couldn't find a cross browser spell check editor.

Most of them do not work in IE. Please guide me if I am missing something or I am wrong or kindly recommend a WYSIWYG editor to be used in asp.net forms which should be checking spells on client side and not on server side.

Thanks a lot.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The DevExpress library has an [HTML Editor with spell checking](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxHTMLEditorDemos/Dialogs/SpellChecking.aspx).
- The Telerik library [also does](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/spellchecker/defaultcs.aspx).

Probably others like Infragistics or Obout also have such features.

Comment: Uwe Keim, these are probably not free and more over these do not work from client side; it is what these demo shown. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The spellchecker integrated in [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo) works in IE last time that I checked it. And in the forums there's another plugin using other integration if you don't want to rely on a 3rd party.